# Output Liquibase log through TinyLog

Tags: liquibase, tinylog

I want to use TinyLog to log Liquibase output. On the Liquibase website I found the information that they are now using JUL for logging: https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/extensions/extension-upgrade-guides/lb-4.0-upgrade-guide.html?Highlight=logger#How_logging_works

So it seems there is no need to implement an own logger based on the AbstractLogger anymore. Instead I tried to forwared the JUL logging to TinyLog. Therefore I followed the instruction on https://tinylog.org/v2/download-preview/#java-util-logging-jul
Now instead of get the Logging of Liquibase I get a StachOverflowError.

I entered the code: `org.tinylog.jul.JulTinylogBridge.activate();`
to a ServletContextListener that is executed on startup. As soon as the first log method is called I get:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.tinylog.runtime.ModernJavaRuntime.getCallerStackTraceElement(ModernJavaRuntime.java:96)
    at org.tinylog.runtime.RuntimeProvider.getCallerStackTraceElement(RuntimeProvider.java:143)
    at org.tinylog.core.TinylogLoggingProvider.log(TinylogLoggingProvider.java:164)
    at org.tinylog.jul.BridgeHandler.publish(BridgeHandler.java:44)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:979)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:1006)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:1172)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:173)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.debug(DirectJDKLog.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at org.tinylog.runtime.ModernJavaRuntime.getCallerStackTraceElement(ModernJavaRuntime.java:96)
    at org.tinylog.runtime.RuntimeProvider.getCallerStackTraceElement(RuntimeProvider.java:143)
    at org.tinylog.core.TinylogLoggingProvider.log(TinylogLoggingProvider.java:164)
```

Comment: ServletContextListener sounds like Java EE or Jakarta EE. Do you use a web server, application server, or Spring Boot?

Comment: I use a servlet container (Tomcat 9) and therefor a ServletContextListener that runs on startup. Besides this I do have CDI (Weld) included.

Answer (score 0):

Web servers like Tomcat have their own logging backend that cannot be easily disabled. Since Tomcat uses `java.util.logging` as its native logging backend, you can't redirect log entries to tinylog via the `jul-tinylog` bridge.

In general, when using web or application servers, it is recommended to use the `tinylog-api` together with a server adaptor instead of the native `tinylog-impl` backend. For Tomcat, [`tinylog-jul`](https://tinylog.org/v2/download/#java-util-logging-based-servers) is the correct artifact. You don't need any bindings nor bridges for third-party logging APIs. So, you have to remove `jul-tinylog` from your classpath. Instead, you need to configure your logging through Tomcat instead of tinylog. However, you can still  use the tinylog logging API, of course.

If you want to output log entries via Tomcat and `tinylog-impl` in parallel, you can do so by adding both `tinylog-impl` and `tinylog-jul` to your classpath. In this case, all log entries output via the tinylog logging API will be submitted to the Tomcat logging backend and the tinylog backend in parallel. Unfortunately, this only affects log entries that are output via the tinylog logging API, and you cannot output log entries from Liquibase via the tinylog backend.